# Is exFAT less efficient at utilising disk space than HFS+?

Tags: partitioning, formatting, exfat, hfs+, size

I'm using `rsync` to copy all files from one 3TB external disk formatted as HFS+ to another 3TB external disk formatted as exFAT.

I've double checked both disks are exactly the same size and formatted the destination disk right before I began the copy, and in fact the source disk has 38GB space, so there's about 2962 GB of files (1TB = 1000GB on my system).

`rsync` has failed around 90% of the way through having filled up the destination disk. Can this be explained by differences between HFS+ and exFAT? Is exFAT much more wasteful of disk space when storing files compared to HFS+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

The reason is due to the big block size by default in exFAT. Just reformat it with a smaller block size and it'll work

However also note that macOS will create a lot of hidden `._` files when copying using Finder to store the file metadata, which consumes even more space compared to HFS+. You should copy using command line to avoid creating those files

---

Actually exFAT so simple that it's *much more efficient* in disk usage than other more advanced file systems like NTFS, ext4, APFS, HFS+... **providing *block size* is the same**, because the more complex a file system is, the more metadata it requires. Just format a new partition in any of those file systems and you'll see that the used space in the blank drive is much larger than exFAT:

- [New ext4 partition and used space](https://askubuntu.com/q/131516/253474)
- [Why does my freshly-formatted HFS+ disk have 450 MB of data on it?](https://superuser.com/q/222127/241386)
- [Why is there large used space after erasing external drive with disk utility?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3610129)

However the thing is that **exFAT has much bigger *block size* by default**. A 3 TB drive will have 1 MiB block size compared to 4 KiB on other file systems. See [1-byte file takes up 2 MB (yes, megabytes) on 6 TB exFAT Veracrypt volume. Why?](https://superuser.com/q/1272907/241386) for the default cluster sizes on exFAT:

```
Volume size   Cluster size
  500 GiB          128 KiB
 1000 GiB          256 KiB
 1500 GiB          512 KiB
 2000 GiB          512 KiB
 3000 GiB            1 MiB
 4000 GiB            1 MiB
 5000 GiB            2 MiB
 8000 GiB            2 MiB
10000 GiB            4 MiB
20000 GiB            8 MiB
```

That means if you have a 640 KiB file, you waste nothing in HFS+ but 384 KiB when storing it in exFAT. As a result an exFAT disk will fill up much faster by default. You must **reformat the exFAT partition and choose a smaller block size** to waste less space

## See also

- [Same files have different "size on disk" on new drive](https://superuser.com/q/1432383/241386)
- [Why is "size on disk" much bigger than "size" when I copy data from NTFS to exFAT?](https://superuser.com/q/513835/241386)
- [Please explain wasted space on an exFAT formatted external hard drive](https://superuser.com/q/365739/241386)

Answer (score 1):

`> much more wasteful of disk space` - there will always be differences in efficiency between filesystems. And this will inevitably show as you get closer to maximum capacity of similarly sized disks.

Just a difference on allocation block size will make a huge impact, e.g. lesser efficiency when you have a lot of **small** files and a comparatively large allocation block size.

Comment: For what it is worth: Reading about 'FFS' FastFileSystem for AmigaOS might be a good learning experience - [AmigaDOS manual - google search](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#q=amigados+manual&safe=off)