Massive Difference in Size and Size on Disk (External Drive)
I'm getting a huge difference in the Size vs the Size on Disk of a copy of a folder I've made to an external HDD. I've read up a bit on cluster size / allocation units, so I would imagine this has something to do with that, but could it really cause an almost four-times increase to the Size on Disk?
This is what I'm seeing in the Properties of the folder in question.
Mainly, I just want to see if anyone has any ideas as to the reason behind this 4x difference in size disparity, and whether there's a way to fix it somehow without reformatting the drive. It is a lot of data, but the transfer speeds were exceedingly slow, even for an HDD (averaging 10MB/s). Any ideas on what could be causing this? This is a new, previously unused drive, and my cable/ports are fine.
Additionally, I'm on Windows11, and my drive is formatted ExFAT with the intention of being compatible with MacOS as well. For what it's worth, the drive will not even mount when I connect it to my Mac, and when I try to mount manually in Disk Utility, I get an error saying it could not mount. No issues mounting in Windows though.
I appreciate it!

If the data is compressed, then the original or restored files might occupy much more space than the backup. Please [edit] your question and add details about the backup software you used and how exactly you see the values shown in the image.

I should have specified: No backup software, just a copy/transfer of files from onboard drive to external drive, and no compression (at least not intentionally).

Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Don't use comments for this purpose. The properties of what did you check. Showing the whole window might avoid asking for clarification.

What is the allocation unit size in the filesystem? AFAIK for exFAT it can be even 32 MiB. If you had e.g. 60,000 relatively small files and you lost about 30 MiB per each, then the difference between the total size on disk and the total size would be about 1800 GiB. So yes, the difference you observed is possible and normal, if the allocation unit size is that big and so many files are that small. Now the question is: is this the case here?

@Kamil Maciorowski Thanks for your comment, it appears you were correct. My disk allocation seems to be as you said, 32MB. I was not expecting that to be possible! Thanks.

duplicates: https://superuser.com/q/1432383/241386, https://superuser.com/q/785129/241386, https://superuser.com/q/66825/241386

After using chkdsk I found that the allocation size is indeed very high, 32MB in this case. I confirmed this by creating a 1KB .txt file, as others have suggested in similar posts. The size on disk is 32MB. I suppose I will have to reformat after all....
